# Normalize csv files using python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, normalize

I ve tried several times to normalize a csv file.
What I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy

import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
norm1 = x / np.linalg.norm(x)
norm2 = normalize(x[:,np.newaxis], axis=0).ravel()
print np.all(norm1 == norm2)
```

the error that I got:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
ImportError: No module named sklearn.preprocessing
```

But I downloaded scipy version 0.18.1 which supports preprocessing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sklearn != scipy`.

Comment: should i download sklearn too? I am not getting your point @divakar

Comment: Well since you mentioned you have Scipy, but you are trying to use `sklearn`, my comment was on that. sklearn and Scipy are two different packackes. So, to use `sklearn`, you need to check if you have `sklearn`. Just do `import sklearn` and see what it says.

Comment: import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn

Comment: My concern is to normalize the csv data before plotting

Comment: it could be that , you pip install the package, but you have facing a problem of running it , because of missing the c - libraries, use python Anaconda distribution . https://www.continuum.io/downloads and replace your entire python , this distribution will take care for dependency , if u use "conda install ..." instead of "pip install ..."

Comment: Can I remove pip so that I can install anaconda. otherwise, it would be difficult to install anaconda @sami

Comment: On my machine i use both , as there are few packages that arn't found on conda, on those cases ancoda fallback to pip.  yoiu can remove the pip , i think that the anconda is coming with pip as well

Answer (score 0):

Please install sklearn package below.

pip install -U scikit-learn